# Swift get values from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I'm trying to parse the JSON response below using the following code but can't seem to get it to work, how would I do this?  Im trying to get "**user_guid**" and all the "**entity_guid**" in images.

SWIFT

```
        do {
            var entity_guid : Int = 0
            var user_guid : Int = 0
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            // Parse JSON data
            let jsonP = jsonResult?["result"] as! [AnyObject]
            for jsonL in jsonP {
                user_guid = jsonL["user_guid"] as! Int
                entity_guid = jsonL["entity_guid"] as! Int
            }


        } catch {

        }
```

JSON

```
{
 "status":0,
 "result":{
  "user_guid":139219,
  "images":[
   {
    "entity_guid":572356
   },
   {
    "entity_guid":572354
   },
   {
    "entity_guid":572352
   }
]
}
}
```

Comment: `result` is an object (dictionary), not an array.

Comment: 1. Why use `NSDictionary`? 2. Why all the crash operators (`!`)? 3. Why are you trying to get the value of `user_guid` in the loop when there's only one and it's not in the same array as the `entity_guid` values?

Comment: ... 3. Why `AnyObject`? 4. Why `.mutableContainers` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
do {
        var entity_guid : Int = 0
        var user_guid : Int = 0
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]

        // Parse JSON data
        let jsonP = jsonResult?["result"] as! [String:Any]
        user_guid = jsonP["user_guid"] as! Int
        let images = jsonP["images"] as! [[String:Int]]
        for jsonL in images {
            entity_guid = jsonL["entity_guid"]!
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` in Swift 3?

Comment: ... and why are you using `AnyObject` in Swift 3? It's `Any`

Comment: @vadian, Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types. AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type. AnyObject is not deprecated in Swift3. I know that its definitely an object of a class type, why should I use "Any" and convert it later to an object. So I used AnyObject instead of Any

Comment: All types `JSON` supports are exclusively structs in Swift therefore `Any`, see [Swift Blog: Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

Comment: @vadian, Thanks for educating me. I've updated the code. By the way, you can modify the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code and try to check. You must use `Swift` datatypes wherever possible.

```
do {
    var entity_guid : Int = 0
    var user_guid : Int = 0
    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]

     guard let jsonP = jsonResult["result"] as [String: Any] else {
     return
    }
     user_guid = jsonP["user_guid"] as! Int
     if let jsonArr = jsonP["images"] as? [String] {
        for image in jsonArr {
            entity_guid = image["entity_guid"] as! Int
         }
}
```

Comment: You have the wrong data type for `jsonArr`. It's needs to be an array of dictionary, not an array of String. Look at the JSON.